# Test two text in different activies

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

On Activity A, I click on a button and call Activity B. And then I matches if addressNickNameView from Activity B is the same on itemAddressNickNameView

```
     onView(withId(R.id.addressNickNameView))
            .check(matches(withId(R.id.itemAddressNickNameView)))`
```

But I facing this problem.

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with id: 2131363004' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: with id: br.com.fastshop.ecommerce.mock.teste:id/itemAddressNickNameView
>   Got: "TextInputEditText{id=2131362631, res-name=component_fast_edittext_edit_text_cpf, visibility=VISIBLE, width=998, height=72, has-focus=false ....

Comment: are you looking to match the value of `addressNickNameView` with `itemAddressNickNameView` or are you looking to match the actual views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Matcher is able to work like that across activities.  You need to capture the value from the first activity before going to the second activity, something like:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<ActivityA> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(ActivityA.class);

@Test
public void test() {
    EditText editTextA = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.itemAddressNickNameView);
    String textA = editTextA.getText().toString();

    // Move to Activity B
    onView(R.id.button).perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.addressNickNameView)).check(matches(withText(textA)));
}
```